# i am using 20 different functions in one query. it takes 6 hrs to execute. if i use package is there any difference

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

i am using 20 different functions in one query. it takes 6 hrs to execute. if i put those functions in one package and call them through package will it increase the performancr or not

Comment: No. Declaring them `deterministic` (if they are deterministic) could help, or `pragma udf` in 12c, or wrapping them in `select from dual` subqueries to get some scalar subquery caching, or abandoning functions and putting the logic in SQL. It all depends on what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Packages are definitely the way to go, but more so for coding standards reasons then performance. You're unlikely to see much, if any difference in performance provided your business logic remains identical.

This is worth a read where use of packages over procedures is discussed. They also talk about performance: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537